# Mac OS and iOS support for Integrated Windows Authentication & IIS

Tags: ios, macos, iis, active-directory, kerberos

Is it possible to use Integrated Windows Authentication on a Mac OS or iOS device connecting to a IIS website on a Active Directory domain?

I think that I need to be researching Kerberos support. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to approach this?

Comment: You can try DirectControl from centrify.com.  They have a free version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You've got to configure your Mac as described in http://training.apple.com/pdf/wp_integrating_active_directory_ml.pdf (chapter "How to Integrate OS X with Active Directory").